# How to hide the SKU in single product page in certain category?

Tags: woocommerce

I am a newbie of woocommerce. I am going to remove the sku in single product page but only in certain category which is XXX, however, the code below doesn't work somehow. Can you guys help me and point where I did wrong please? Thanks a lot.

```
add_filter( 'wc_product_sku_enabled', 'st_remove_product_page_sku' );

function st_remove_product_page_sku( $enabled ) {
if ( is_product() && has_term('XXX' ) ) {
    return false;
}
return $enabled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out..
I forgot the $taxonomy in the has_term

```
has_term('XXX','product_cat')
```

It will do the job.